# Move files according to number in filename

Tags: shell, variables, grep, mv

I am trying to move files in folders according to a number in their names.
Files are names like `fooNNN_bar.txt` I would like to organise them like `/NNN/fooNNN_bar.txt`

Here is what I have for now. It prints me the folder each file would have to move to. I'm not sure how to collect the number to add it into a mv command. Is this even the correct way to do it?

```
#!/bin/bash
  for filename in foo*.txt; 
  do 
  echo "${filename}" | grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,4}';
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your grep works as you want:

```
#!/bin/bash
  for filename in foo*.txt; do 
      num=$(echo "${filename}" | grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,4}')
      mkdir -p "$num"
      mv "$filename" "$num"
done
```

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks.

Comment: No need for the echo, pipe and grep: `num="${filename//[^0-9]}"`.