# In Bash, move files to directories according to their names

Tags: linux, bash

I have lots of files whose names have the following format : 
`GroupName - SongName-id.mp3` where id is 11 characters long. I'd like to move them in directories such as the file `GroupName - SongName-id.mp3` will be renamed `GroupName/SongName.mp3`
I've done some research on the web (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37494081/move-files-according-to-number-in-filename)), but I don't know how to retrieve the `GroupName` and `SongName` using grep.
EDIT : the GroupName directory can already exist or not, it depends.

I first tried using the following script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
for filename in *.mp3;do
    group=$(echo $filename | grep -oE ".* - .*-.{11}\.mp3")
    # I don't know what regex should I place above

    # do all the other stuff here ...
done
```

Comment: does `GroupName` already exist?

Comment: Please do a little research first. There are *many* related questions already on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @chepner Yes I saw but after looking, I still have no idea how to retrieve GroupName and SongName.

Comment: Include what *you* have *tried* in the question; do not just link to another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following complex solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -regextype sed -regex '[^-]* - [^-]*-.\{11\}\.mp3' -print0 | while read -r -d $'\0' file
do
    IFS=\; read -a parts  <<< $(sed -E 's:.+/(\S[^/-]+\S) - (\S+)-\S{11}(\.mp3):\1;\2\3:' <<< "$file")
    mkdir -p "${parts[0]}"
    mv "$file" "${parts[0]}/${parts[1]}"
done
```

---

***Details***:

- `-regextype sed` (in `find` command) - set type of regular expressions
- `-regex` (in `find` command) - option used to find files by regex pattern
- `-print0` and `$'\0'` - ensure separating filenames by zero (null) character
- `read -a parts` - read `sed` result (returns *groupname* and *filename* separated by `;`) into array
- `mkdir -p "${parts[0]}"` - create directory with a name of *groupname* if not exists

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! However, it seems to be broken when there are spaces in GroupName ... Is there a way to fix it ? I was thinking about replacing all blank spaces by `%` but I don't know if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: you didn't mention that in your question